# RadDataControl. Hide add new logical opearor button

Tags: wpf, telerik

Is there a way to hide the add logical operator button?

The green one with three white dots at the end of each filter descriptor

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this attribute to the component does it

`CanUserCreateCompositeFilters="False"`

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the control template with Blend to achieve your goal.